# LINQ with RX Extensions

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, system.reactive

I was under the impression that the LINQ query language worked for IObservable as it does for IEnumerable with the ReactiveExtensions. I have the following code

```
Public Sub Foo(source As IObservable(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)))
  Dim filtered = source.Where(Function(x) x.Item1 > 10).Select(Function(x) x.Item1 + x.Item2)
  Dim filtered2 = From x In source Where x.Item1 > 10 Select x.Item1 + x.Item2
End Sub

Public Sub Bar(source As IEnumerable(Of Tuple(Of Integer, Integer)))
  Dim filtered = source.Where(Function(x) x.Item1 > 10).Select(Function(x) x.Item1 + x.Item2)
  Dim filtered2 = From x In source Where x.Item1 > 10 Select x.Item1 + x.Item2
End Sub
```

The code for the IEnumerable version is OK. However for the LINQ version of Foo ( second line )
I get a late binding disallowed error on

```
x.Item1
```

When I hover over **x** the Intellisense says it is of type object instead of
type tuple. However the object query version of the same operation ( first line )
compiles ok. I've imported

```
Imports system.reactive.linq
```

Am I missing another reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your code in the question works fine for me. I don't get your error.

Perhaps try importing `System.Reactive` too, but other than that it looks fine.